# Integral $\int\sqrt{1-\cos2x}~dx=$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

So here is the problem I'm working with

$$\int\sqrt{1-\cos2x}~dx$$

I'm assuming that I'll need to use the trig identity
$2\sin^2x=1-\cos2x$ . But where do I go from there?

$$\int\sqrt{2\sin^2x}~dx$$

Do I split the $\sqrt{2}$ and the $\sqrt{\sin^2x}$ so that I have $$\int\sqrt{2}\sin x~dx$$ and do integration by parts?

Comment: $\int a f(x) dx = a \int f (x) dx$

Comment: $\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}=|\sin(x)|.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can simplify as you did at the end, but no need for integration by parts! Recall, $\sqrt 2$ is merely a constant!

$$\int \sqrt 2 \sin x \,dx = \sqrt 2 \int \sin x \,dx = -\sqrt 2 \cos x + C$$

You did the "hardest part" by recognizing the trigonometric identity here. The rest is simply knowing that $\int \sin x = -\cos x + C$

Comment: It's really that simple? That is the step I wanted to take, but it looked way too simple to be mixed in with the review problems I'm doing. Thank you once again, I'll accept the answer when it allows me to. I'll go ahead and work on the next ones.

Comment: Yes, it really is that simple!

Comment: But it is not a true answer to the question under consideration.

Comment: It is beautiful and don't make it more beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Integrate $\verts{\sin\pars{x}}$, for example, as follows.

With $x > 0$:
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{x}\verts{\sin\pars{t}}\,\dd t =
x\verts{\sin\pars{x}} - \int_{0}^{x}t\ \sgn\pars{\sin\pars{t}}\cos\pars{t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=
x\verts{\sin\pars{x}} - \int_{0}^{x}\sgn\pars{\sin\pars{t}}\phi'\pars{t}\,\dd t
\quad\mbox{where}\quad\phi\pars{x} \equiv \int_{0}^{x}t\cos\pars{t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]
&\int_{0}^{x}\verts{\sin\pars{t}}\,\dd t = x\verts{\sin\pars{x}} - \sgn\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\phi\pars{x} + \int_{0}^{x}\phi\pars{t}\bracks{2\delta\pars{\sin\pars{t}}\cos\pars{t}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=
x\verts{\sin\pars{x}} - \sgn\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\phi\pars{x} + 2\int_{0}^{x}\phi\pars{t}\sum_{n = 0}^{n\pi \leq x}\delta\pars{t - n\pi}\cos\pars{t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=
x\verts{\sin\pars{x}} - \sgn\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\phi\pars{x} +
2\sum_{n = 0}^{n\pi \leq x}\pars{-1}^{n}\phi\pars{n\pi}
\end{align}
Also
\begin{align}
\phi\pars{x}&=x\sin\pars{x} - \int_{0}^{x}\sin\pars{t}\,\dd t
=
x\sin\pars{x} + \cos\pars{x} - 1
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{x}\verts{\sin\pars{t}}\,\dd t
=
\sgn\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\bracks{1 - \cos\pars{x}} + 2\sum_{n = 0}^{n\pi \leq x}\pars{-1}^{n}\bracks{\cos\pars{n\pi} - 1}
\end{align}
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\int_{0}^{x}\verts{\sin\pars{t}}\,\dd t
=
\sgn\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\bracks{1 - \cos\pars{x}} + 4\sum_{n = 0}^{\pars{2n + 1}\pi \leq x}1}
$$